# Page not found Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

Tags: apache, shibboleth, tiki-wiki

I am using Apache as host for Shibboleth and Tiki 21. After succesful IdP login, Tiki-webpage ends up telling:

`Page not found Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST`

When using Shibboleth from Tiki the shibd logfile is silent on callback from IdP which is in contrast to my other uses of Shibboleth on the same host.

On callback from IdP Apache error log says:

```
==> error_log <==
[php7:notice] No route found - full:/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/themes/base_files/css/tiki_base.css query:, referer: https://wiki.mydomain/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
```

Anyone having a clue on a solution to this problem?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug, and sounds like it might be tricky to fix without duplicating that setup, but worth starting the process off, here: https://dev.tiki.org/File-a-bug

Comment: Thank you @jonnybradley! It is a pretty straight forward setup of Tiki 21 and Shibboleth. I have tried to register to be able to file a bug, but it seems impossible as the manual acceptance of the registration never takes place. Do you know any trick to get registered?